# Horizontal Form Class not being applied bootstrap Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to create a horizontal form in razor but I cannot seem to apply the css. Everything else has the proper CSS but when i try to add the class to the BeginForm or even the normal  it does not work.

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("Default", "Employee", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" })))
{
        <h2>Employee Search</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Company: ", new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("cono", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("First Name: ", new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBox("firstName", Session["firstname"], new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Last Name: ", new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBox("lastName", Session["lastname"], new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Branch: ", new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("branch", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BranchList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Sales Rep: ", new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBox("salesRep", Session["salesrep"], new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Status Type: ", new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("statusType", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.StatusTypeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="DefaultPost" value="Search" />
            <input type="button" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Default", "Employee")' " />
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the div wrapping the labels
2. Give the labels a column class `col-sm-3`
3. Add a column class `col-sm-9` to the div wrapping the inputs
4. Make sure the `form-group` div wraps the both the label and the div wrapping the input.

Razor syntax

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Company: ", new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.DropDownList("cono", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyList, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Plain HTML format...

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
```